# bash test yields "echo: command not found"

Tags: bash, testing, command, echo

Ok, something funny happens all of a sudden. This test

```
for i in `cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt `; do [ -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/$i ] || echo $i; done
```

used to work fine (for every entry in the file liste.txt try to find a corresponding directory, print the name if not found) and used to yield the names of directories missing. Now this command yields

```
 echo: command not found
 echo: command not found
 echo: command not found
(...)
```

I've tried using [[...]] and "test" instead of "[ ..]" but to no avail.

Any ideas what might have happened with my beloved bash while I wasn't looking :) ?

Thanks,
 Christian.

Edit (set -x output):

```
(...)
+ for i in '`cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt`'
+ '[' -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/THE_GHOST_WRITER.lsdvd.xml ']'
+ for i in '`cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt`'
+ '[' -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/THE_IMAGINARIUM_OF_DOCTOR_PARNASSUS.lsdvd.xml ']'
+ for i in '`cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt`'
+ '[' -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/THE_INFORMANT.lsdvd.xml ']'
+ for i in '`cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt`'
+ '[' -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/THE_INTERNATIONAL.lsdvd.xml ']'
+ for i in '`cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt`'
+ '[' -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/THE_MEN_WHO_STARE_AT_GOATS.lsdvd.xml ']'
+ for i in '`cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt`'
+ '[' -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/THE_OTHER_MAN.lsdvd.xml ']'
+ for i in '`cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt`'
+ '[' -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/THE_QUEEN.lsdvd.xml ']'
+ for i in '`cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt`'
+ '[' -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/THE_READER.lsdvd.xml ']'
+ for i in '`cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt`'
+ '[' -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/THE_REBOUND.lsdvd.xml ']'
+ $'\302\240echo' THE_REBOUND
+ '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
+ /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- $'\302\240echo'
 echo: command not found
+ return 127
(...)
```

Comment: have you try to double-quote `$i` ?

Comment: If you replace the end of the line with `echooooo $1; done`, does it give an error `echooooo: command not found`? That "command not found" error is what I get when I type junk at a bash command prompt. What if you replace it with `/bin/echo`?

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of your script and watch each command that the shell executes.

Comment: My findings: Double quoting $i: no avail, same error.  echoooo: command not found.

Answer (score 38):

If you look closely, you will see it's printing:

```
 echo: command not found
```

with a leading space, rather than:

```
echo: command not found
```

`set -x` makes this much clearer when it prints:

```
$'\302\240echo' THE_REBOUND
```

`0302 0240` is octal UTF-8 for a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Try deleting the space between `|` and `echo` and type a normal space.

---

Chances are, the file was edited on a Mac, where a non-breaking space can be entered accidentally if you press <kbd>Option</kbd> at the same time as <kbd>Space</kbd>.

If you're using Vim, you can make non-breaking spaces more obvious by using the [listchars option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'listchars').  For example:

```
set listchars+=nbsp:% list
```

See [Making Vim highlight suspicious characters](https://wincent.com/blog/making-vim-highlight-suspicious-characters) for some more ideas.

On Linux, non-breaking space is either <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, so you're probably not going to type that by accident.

---

For anyone interested, it's possible to manually convert the octal bytes to UTF-8 using the [UTF-8 table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design) from the UTF-8 Wikipedia article.

But by far the easiest way I found was using Python:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name('\302\240'.decode('utf-8'))
'NO-BREAK SPACE'
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: The code below is still fine, but the issue is probably in `$'\302\240echo'`: There seems to be **unknown characters** in your text file. Try removing the couple characters before echo and then typing them again.

It could well be a *quoting* issue. Also, you could save some time by avoiding the [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html):

```
while IFS= read -r; do [ -f "/mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/$REPLY" ] || echo "$REPLY"; done < /mnt/usb/liste.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you run simply:

```
for i in `cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt `; do
    echo $i
done
```

For one thing, do you notice anything abnormal about the filenames (spaces, newlines, special characters, etc)?  If so, you will need to quote the filename to keep the shell from mis-interpreting it.

Also, try using a normal `if` statement instead of the logical OR:

```
for i in `cat /mnt/usb/liste.txt `; do
    if [ ! -f /mnt/usb/lsdvd.xml/$i ]; then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: The simple for-echo-done loop works fine, nothing unusual about the filenames. Actually, the are quite nice: no spaces, not even numbers.

Comment: The for-if-then-fi-done loop works fine, so it must be something about the || and strange unquoted strings, but I can't seem to find anything unusual about the files and their names.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
for f in $(< d2.lst); do [ -f ./d2/$f ] || echo $f ; done
```

Just my own filenames, directories, and suggested construct $(...) instead of backticks, and with < instead of cat.

Maybe a dos/windows linefeed in your list? View it with `less`.